# GWT: Granularity of Places and ActivityMappers

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, gwt-activities, gwt-places

I'm finally starting to "get" GWT. At any time, a `PlaceChangeEvent` can be fired on the app's `EventBus` like so:

```
History.newItem("token-for-some-new-place");
```

This adds the event to the bus, whereby a registered `ActivityManager` scoops it up and consults its internal `ActivityMapper` to give it the `Activity` associated with the `PlaceChangeEvent`'s `Place`.

The `Activity` (similar to a presenter or controller object from MVP/MVC) then obtains any data that is needed (via RPC calls to the server) and executes any business logic and configures the final view (typically a `Composite` of some sort) to display.

As long as we're talking about a super-simple GWT app that only has one display region on its host page, then like I said, I "get" it.

Where I am choking now is what happens when you have an app that contains multiple display regions (areas that can be updated asynchronously from one another).

So I ask:

1. How granular are `ActivityMapper`s supposed to be? Is there just one app-wide `AppActivityMapper` that maps all `Place`s to all `Activity`ies, or should there be some sort of `ActivityMapper` hierarchy/decomposition, where you have multiple mappers? (And if your answer to this is something along the lines of "*this depends on the needs of your application*" then please explain what requirements/needs drive the appropriate level of granularity!)
2. If a `Place` represents a URL token in your app (for the sake of making the `Place` a bookmarkable state), then what happens when you have a more complex app that has multiple display regions (D1, D2, D3). How does one URL token (i.e. `http://myapp.com/#token-for-some-new-place`) map to D1, D2 and D3? Wouldn't that mean `ActivityMapper#getActivity` would have to be capable of returning a list of activities (`List<Activity>`) whose `start(AcceptsOneWidget, EventBus)` methods would all get callled?

Thanks for any help here - code examples always rock.

Comment: If you use places, I'd advise you to use *only* places (`PlaceController.goTo()`), not the low-level `History`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas but that is an answer to a question that I didn't ask.

Comment: And that's why I'm adding it as a comment ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Place` represents, well, a place. It answers the existential questions of *where did I come from?*, *where am I?* and *where am I going to?*.

For a given place, the *screen* that's displayed to the user can be complex, and divided into a bunch of *display regions*. Each one is governed by an `ActivityManager`, which asks an `ActivityMapper` which `Activity` to use for a given place, making everything loosely coupled (activities don't (have to) know where they're being used, for which place, which other activities are running concurrently, etc.)

So, you won't have a mapper that'd return a list of activities, but a list of mappers each returning one activity.

See:

- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-places/
- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-places-part-ii/
- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities/
- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni/

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Broyer (+1) - however, here you're saying that a `Place` exists at the page/screen level, whereas `ActivityManagers` and `ActivityMappers` exist at the display region level (where a *screen* consists of 1+ *display regions*). **But how is this possible?** If display regions D1, D2 and D3 can each exist in 5 bookmarkable states, and they all belong to the same screen, then the screen can exist in 5^3 = 125 bookmarkable states! How can a single (screen-level) Place represent 125 states!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying here, but my tentative answer would be: all display regions change at the same time (that doesn't mean they *have* to change though, you can have some of them display the same activity as for another place, but still thay've been asked for the activity to display for the current place). Here on StackOverflow, the menu bar (with the logo), the "tagged" section at the top-right, the "community bulletin", the ad and the "related" below, and finally the main area with the question and answers; 1 URL (place) dictates what appears in each area (activities).

Comment: Ahhh...so to use my example above, if display regions D1, D2 and D3 can each exist in 5 bookmarkable states, then given a URL of, say, `http://myapp.com/#some-state`, they will each have their own, independent mappers that know what `Activity` to show. That makes sense, thanks!